# Why can't I use data forwarding in this exercise?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines, mips

as the title says, I am wondering why this exercise doesn't show a data forwarding from the "ex" stage of 2nd instruction to "ex" stage of 3rd instruction.

P.S. the architecture is MIPS (with simplified 5 stage cycle).

Thank you in advance
[image]